# Class Restriction in OWL

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

Using OWL (I am using Protege), I created classes Window and Door both of which are subclasses of Ingress.  I also have classes called Dwelling, Survey, and Requirement.

How do I create Requirements - to be used during a survey?  Every ingress need not have a lock, but a dwelling fails a Survey when an Ingress has no lock. I am trying to create a set of Requirements to be verified during a survey; some of those Requirements may pass and some may fail.

Comment: Its kind of validation issue - have you tried SHACL?

Comment: @Antoniossss I have not tried, but I will investigate.

Comment: What do you mean by Rule and a subclass stating restrictions on other classes?

Comment: @Ignazio `Rule` is just a domain specific class it looks like- so not what we assume as rule in OWL/SWRL context

Comment: That's what I thought, hence the request for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is that every `Ingress` has a lock, define `Lock` as a class and a property `hasLock`, then make `Ingress` subclass of `exist hasLock Lock`.

Comment: the key point to mention is the dfference between *"must have"* and *"has"* - clearly, OWL is not a constraint language, thus, SHACL was suggested.

Comment: @Ignazio - thank you for your answer. Every ingress need not have a lock, but rather that a dwelling fails a survey when a window (or door) has no lock. I am trying to create a set of requirements to be verified during a survey - some of those requirements will pass and some will fail.

Comment: @Upperstage then you need a constraint language which OWL is not. Use SHACL or SHeX  instead